# Memory test that fails with a different address each time

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, apple-hardware-test

I had problems (strange patterns on the display and reboots) with my Late 2011 Macbook Pro, so I ran Apple Hardware Test on my computer, and it found memory errors. The thing is that every time  I run the AHT, the error is slightly different. The first time, I got:

> 4MEM/62/40000000: 0x83a65498

The second time:

> 4MEM/62/40000000: 0x836dc298

I then swapped my two memory sticks and got this error:

> 4MEM/62/40000000: 0x842e1198

I am assuming that the hex number is the address where the test fails…

It always takes about 13.5 minutes of tests for the error to appear. [Rambler](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/Rember/) also found an error during one pass of tests out of two:

> FAILURE! Data mismatch at local BUFA address 0x000000012479b930, BUFB
>   address 0x00000001c96da130 BUFA Data: 0xffffffff80000000, BUFB Data:
>   0xffffdfff80000000

Memtest86 did not find any problem after 4 passes.

Because the error is different each time, I was wondering if I should suspect something else than a memory stick being bad, something like the memory controller.

**UPDATE**:

However, I am not getting any error message, if I run the AHT while there is only one memory stick in my MBP.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find documentation of what these fields mean.

However, given that memory failures that I've seen and those posted by others all appear to be around "address" 0x842XXXXX, I suspect that this is not in fact the address. It may be the pattern being written to some address when the failure occurred.

The field where you have a value of 62 seems to be the only one that varies significantly. It may be that this value represents the address to some very course degree (eg. maybe 1-64 could represent one DIMM and 65-128 the other; or maybe odd numbers vs even numbers).

It would be nice if Apple would document these very basic and useful error code formats.